# How to terminte mysql sql file execution without run left statements

Tags: mysql

Suppose that we have a table named test

```
create table test 
(
    id int not null,
    primary key (id)
) engine = innodb;
```

and a sql file 1.sql

```
 start transaction;
 insert into test(id) values(1);
 select sleep(100);
 select * from test;
 commit;
```

We run 1.sql with mysql client tool

```
mysql -uroot < 1.sql
```

It will block at "select sleep(100)" statement. If I press "Ctrl-C", mysql client will only
kill the *current statement* and *continue* to execute the left statements. As the result,
the insert will be commit. Is there a method to kill the sql file execution without execute
the left statements?

PS: I tried "Ctrl + \" to abort the mysql client, that will make the query still executed
in the server side because of *do not* send *kill query*

Answer (score 0):

You can open a second connection, check for the session you want to kill with `SHOW PROCESSLIST`, and then use the SQL `KILL` command to terminate it.

See also http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/kill.html

and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-processlist.html

Comment: Thanks for the anwser, but is there any better method?

Answer (score 0):

It should be rolled back, because transaction is not committed yet.(by killing third query).

Comment: It just not rollback and continue to excute "select * from test" and "commit".

Comment: @Chen Kaien, i checked this now on my local, here transaction still alive because we kill the query when it's on process so the control to pass to the next query and execute it,here the transaction is success